# Can we add UDF in excel template through visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba

I have a **excel template(.xlt),** and I want to do custom validation for this can I use macro, I am doing coding in **c#**, When I **pressF11** in visual studio it opens the **macro editor of visual studio but not of excel**...Is there any way to add macro or UDF so that I can use User Defined Function in custom validation of excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write the UDF in VBA (which sounds like the simplest solution) then open the .xlt in Excel, press F11 to get the Excel VBE and add the VBA UDF to a standard module, then save the file as an .xlt typ

Comment: I think its difficult to associate a C# UDF with a particular document (your .xlt), so I would suggest you create a public .NET automation add-in that contains your C# UDF, install it on the systems that need the .XLT, and then the .XLT (and any other Excel workbooks) can call the UDF

Comment: Thanks for u r response sir,Can u provide the link or step by step procedure to do this...?       thanking you

Comment: Its rally cool but i can not add UDF to custom validation of excel it gives me an error as:You can not use references to other worksheeta or workbooks for data validation criteria.Is there any way to use UDF in custom validation of excel ?